# Dynamic entity name in JpaRepository?

Tags: java, spring, el, spring-data-jpa

I'm using spring `JpaRepository`, and want to provide a generic interface with generic derived SQL queries as follows using `el` expressions:

```
public interface BaseRepo <B> extends CrudRepository<B, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT b FROM #{#entityName} b)
    List<B> findAllB();
}

@Entity
class Booking {} //results in "booking"
```

This works fine! But what if the desired entity contains an underscore? How could I define the strategy of how the el expressions translate the entity name?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "booking_entity")
class BookingEntity {} //results in "bookingentity", missing underscore!
```

Comment: The `@Query` should be in `JPQL`, which *should* be using `BookingEntity`, not `booking_entity`. `@Table` is used by (e.g.) hibernate to map the JPQL to an actual SQL query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the annotation `@Entity(name="booking_entity")`.